# iOS check and create folder c++

Tags: c++, ios

I am working on an iOS Game in xcode.

I have a method where I check if a directory exists and create the directory if it doesn't exist.
Below is the code

```
if(stat(destPath.c_str(), &sb) == -1)
{
    if(mkdir(destPath.c_str(), S_IRWXU) == 0)
    {
        //Folder created
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The issue here is, this works properly with simulator.
But on a real device, this is not working correctly.
I have just started learning iOS development.
Any help would be appreciated. Any ideas on how to do this part?

Comment: Try logging the return value of `mkdir`, so we can help you.

Comment: @JCWasmx86 - The return value is -1.

Comment: what is errno? Try logging it with strerror, so you get a string

Comment: errno is 1. The strerror displays "Operation not permitted"

Comment: You don't have the permission to create a directory in this directory.

Comment: @JCWasmx86 - I might be completely wrong. But this same code executed properly when I ran the app in a simulator. But it didn't work when I ran in an actual device

Answer (score 0):

The simulator will allow you to write to locations that are not writeable on a real device.  Your destPath is probably in one of those locations.  See the [File System Programing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for details.